# Neo4j Avoiding circular results in cypher query

Tags: neo4j, cypher, ontology

I have the Uniform Medical Language System (UMLS) ontologies loaded into Neo4j and relationships between SNOMED concept nodes. There can be multiple types of relationships between any two nodes. The 2015AA release of UMLS and my selection of options has produced 1,256,982 SNOMED nodes and 2,258,642 relationships between them. This query results in the expected 21 child nodes of the SNOMED root node:

```
MATCH (n:MRCONSO{AUI:'A3684559'}) match n<-[*..1]-x return count(*)
```

Increasing the depth of the query causes problems.  This query produces 3338 rows in the return

```
MATCH (n:MRCONSO{AUI:'A3684559'}) match n<-[*..2]-x return id(x)
```

There are 11 rows where the id is not unique. This can also be seen in this query which results in 3327 rows (3338-11)

```
MATCH (n:MRCONSO{AUI:'A3684559'}) match p=shortestpath(n<-[*..2]-x) return id(x)
```

Thus, I can get the unique child node IDs using the shortestpath.  However, the query times are 52 ms and 61745 for the 2nd and 3rd queries, respectfully. Either of these deteriorates with queries of greater depth.

Is there a way to avoid the circularity in the query and thereby reduce the query time?

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Neo4j are you using? Try to update to 2.2.2

Were you able to determine why you get those duplicate ids?
It could be that a child is reachable on two levels

Also your query will output both the level 1 and level 2 children.

Can you output all paths of a certain duplicate id?

Would it be good enough to just get the unique id's ? Then you can use distinct.

```
MATCH (n:MRCONSO{AUI:'A3684559'})
MATCH (n)<-[*..2]-(x) 
RETURN distinct id(x)
```

Do you have an index or constraint on `:MRCONSO(AUI)` ?

Comment: I am using version 2.3.0-M01.  There is an index on AUI. Using the distinct id(x) does speed the query significantly.  BUT, it does not solve the fundamental problem of circularity.  And, I do need more than the node IDs because the basis goal is output of the semantic meaning of and relationship type between the nodes (UMLS concepts).

Comment: Did you check the paths for the duplicates. Cypher uses relationship-uniqueness on a single path but not across multiple paths. So it will never return circular path within but several paths can lead to the same end-node.

Comment: I think you have captured the essence of the problem. By duplicate, I think you mean the same node appearing in a single path. By manually inspecting the output, I can see this is happening. How do I address this in cypher? I've tried 
MATCH path = (n:MRCONSO{AUI:'A3684559'})<-[r*1..3]-(x) RETURN collect(distinct x)
but this too has a long run time.

Comment: How many paths are returned from that query? MATCH path = (n:MRCONSO{AUI:'A3684559'})<-[r*1..3]-(x) RETURN count(*) ?

Comment: Good question.  30,488.  This query takes you from the root of the SNOMED ontology down to every leaf. And there are multiple paths to some descendent nodes. So ... perhaps it is the combination of the number of paths and the circularity that makes this a difficult problem. Using the path method to eliminate duplicate nodes works with a limited number of paths, but this is not the scenario here. This must be a problem in other networks, such as social networks? Perhaps there are some pre-processing steps, before loading relationships into Neo4j, to address this?

Comment: I am trying a different pre-processing now that reduces the number of relationships. Will report back.